# Using re.sub() in python to replace html code

Tags: python, regex, str-replace

I want to make minor changes to my html code to do some formatting. If I have the below code in a python string, how can I use the re.sub() function to replace lines according to my required. Eg. In this case I am trying to add border to my table.

```
<body><table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table></body>
```

I want to convert the above code to something like this :

```
<body><table border=1>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table></body>
```

Comment: HTML is not a regular language; don't parse it with regular expressions. *Use an HTML parser.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.sub(r"(<table)",r"\1 border=1",test_Str)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/55

Comment: Awesome ! That worked like a charm ! Sorry, but i dont have enough reputation to give you a vote up.

Comment: @user3450198 you can accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `re.sub` for this, that's why we have `BeautifulSoup`.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and then

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'your_html_here'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Now you can extract, modify, add, remove and manipulate anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, use BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup("<table></table>", "html.parser")
table = html.find('table')
table.attrs['border'] = 1
```

html now looks like `<table border="1"></table>`

In the example above, I had only one table element, you can iterate over all the table elements if you have more than one.

To get a string (not a BeautifulSoup element) : `html.prettify(formatter="html")`